# How the counter works in assembly

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, counter

Can someone help me to understand how this code works in detail. Currently   i only understand first three lines...

```
        MOV AL,99H
        OUT 06H,AL
        MOV AL,2
NEXT1:  MOV CX,0FFFFH
NEXT2:  LOOP NEXT2
        OUT 02H,AL
        ROL AL,1
        JMP NEXT1
        END
```

Comment: Can you tell us what is exactly bothering you? The `loop` and `rol` instructions? The code just seems to initialize a custom FPGA/device with (possibly) an array of LEDs or something. In a real PC, port 02h is Read-only and, along with port 06, it belongs to the first legacy DMA controller.

Comment: yes, it initializes a custom FPGA but what does MOV CX,0FFFFH mean?

Comment: Surely you can't be confused by a simple `MOV`? It just sets `CX` to `0FFFFh`. It's used for a delay loop.

Comment: There is a nice summary of the 8086 instructions [here](http://www.electronics.dit.ie/staff/tscarff/8086_instruction_set/8086_instruction_set.html). Sometime to understand the role of an instruction you have to keep reading down the source :) Try to identify how the control flows.

Comment: @MargaretBloom : I suspect they are using a flight86 training board. This is a 4.9152mhz 8086 board with up to 64kb memory. There are a couple 8255s. One is available at Port 0x00(Port A), Port 0x02(Port B), Port 0x04(Port C),.Port 0x06(Control port). Writing 99h to control port would make Port A and port C input ports and Port B (0x02) an output port so in this context the code does make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, this looks to me like some kind of LED chaser:

```
         ; send 0x99 (binary 10011001) to Port 6, for whaever reason
        MOV AL,99H
        OUT 06H,AL


        MOV AL,2          ; initialize running bit, 2= 00000010b

NEXT1:  MOV CX,0FFFFH
NEXT2:  LOOP NEXT2        ; this loops 65535 times (decrease 
                          ; CX until 0 is reached)

        OUT 02H,AL        ; send pattern to port 2 (whatever that does)

        ROL AL,1          ; 'rol' shifts left one bit each time ...
                          ; putting the 1 back in on the right side,
                          ; when it drops out

        JMP NEXT1         ; back to the pausing loop
        END
```

on port 2: the following will appear (repeated)

```
(pause)
00000010  
(pause)
00000100  
(pause)
00001000
(pause)
00010000  
(pause)
00100000  
(pause)
01000000
(pause)
10000000
(pause)
00000001
```

What can't be said with the little info you gave us:

- first pattern shown on port2
- length of the pause, depends on your CPUs speed
- what port6 does (probably some initialization)
- what port2 does when the patterns are out'ed

Comment: 099H = 8255 initialization

Comment: I don't think this is a 8255, 0x99 out be "portB to output", but with control port = 0x06, port B would be 0x04, not 0x02 ... or there's some mapping done. however, it's not clear, perhaps `out 6,0x99` will turn on the NC1701's self destruction sequence in 153 seconds? who knows :)

Comment: I'm going on a wild hunch the clock frequency is 4.9152mhz so the delay is probably ~0.2267 seconds

Comment: And if my hunch is right that this is a Flight-86 board Port 0x06 is the 8255 Control Port. Writing 0x99 to it will make Port B (0x02) an output port and Port A (0x00) and Port C(0x04) input ports.

Comment: @MichaelPetch look's like they missed the lowest address pin A15, when they wired the 8255 to the board, isn't usually control port = base + 3, and port A,B,C =base+0 - base+2 ? although a reason for this could be to be able to write 16bit values to them, and still not messing up the other ports

Comment: Wiring for a typical IBM-PC (eg: ports 0x60 to 0x64) would have them addressed consecutively. Flight board staggered them. The second 8255 on the flight board is accessible as ports 0x01(A), 0x03(B), 0x05(C), and 0x07(Control)

Comment: Some links I posted as a comment to another Flight-86 question recently were these ones: A couple academia links regarding the board is here: http://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/EE/ahussain/teaching/Exp_07.pdf and.http://ccse.kfupm.edu.sa/~hazem/coe305/part2-expr01.pdf . Overview and specs of the board: http://otdl.com/Fl8086.pdf